# libtiff build undefined reference to `_imp__TIFFOpen' error

Tags: c, linker, mingw, undefined-reference, libtiff

probably this is a trivial newbie question, however, I can't figure out how to solve it.

I'm trying to build a test program using `libtiff` (test program copied from [here](http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html#Scanlines)). I've downloaded the static library `libtiff.lib` as well as the required header file `tiffio.h`. When I compile the main c function with no problem I have a `main.o` file. When I try to link main.o with `libtiff` using this command

```
gcc -g -Wall -o test.exe ./libtiff.lib ./test.o
```

I have this error:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__TIFFOpen'
```

I've looked into the lib file with `nm -A libtiff.lib` command and I can find this line

```
libtiff.lib:libtiff3.dll:00000000 I __imp__TIFFOpen
```

but it has 2 leading underscores instead of 1 as required by the linker. **I'm using mingw on Windows 7** and all the required files are in the same directory.

No clue how to link with no errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GNU linker links libraries left-to-right in general. You need to place the `.lib` **after** your `test.o` on the command line!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks man, it was so easy. Thanks

Comment: The explanation is that of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/918959 "The linker searches from left to right, and notes unresolved symbols as it go. If a library resolves the symbol, it takes the object files of that library to resolve the symbol (b.o out of libb.a in this case)." - but I couldn't find a clean MinGW duplicate in C instead of these Linux C++ ones :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the the comments, it was sufficient to invert the order of objects passed as arguments:

```
gcc -g -Wall -o test.exe ./test.o ./libtiff.lib
```